# How to get latest last row from an online database and refresh every 10 seconds(Kinvey)

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, kinvey

can please anyone help me with the following:

the following method retrieve data from an online database and i am able to display it but the problem is it takes too long about 1 Minute to display because the application searches through the database to display the latest result from database. can anyone please help me with the application to just go straight to the last rows of the table? so that the application can take few seconds to display data and also be able to refresh every 10 seconds.

here is the method:

```
private class GetAllProductsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            myJavaClient = new Client.Builder(appKey, mastersecret,getApplicationContext()).build();
            myJavaClient.enableDebugLogging();
            myJavaClient.ping(new KinveyPingCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Boolean arg0) {
                    System.out.print("Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                    System.out.println("Failure");
                }
            });

            try {

                myJavaClient.user().loginBlocking(appKey, mastersecret).execute();
                System.out.println("Client login -> "+ myJavaClient.user().isUserLoggedIn());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println("Couldn't login -> " + e);

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Ignore for now

            myJavaClient.appData("tdSensorData", Sensor.class).get(new KinveyListCallback<Sensor>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Sensor[] result) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Get All Worked!\n Got: " + result.length,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        for(Sensor eventID : result)
                        {   

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                            String currentDate = currentDateandTime.substring(0,10);

                            String times = eventID.getDatetime();
                            String tim1 = times.substring(0,10);                

                            if (currentDate .compareTo(tim1)==0){

                            String sens1 = eventID.getSensorr1().toString();                
                            Senso1.setText(sens1);

                            String sens2 = eventID.getSensorr2().toString();
                            Senso2.setText(sens2);

                            String sens3 = eventID.getSensorr3().toString();
                            Senso3.setText(sens3);

                            String tmp = eventID.getTemp();
                            temper.setText(tmp+ " " + "°C");

                            String dat = eventID.getDatetime(); 
                            Device1.setText(dat);
                            }

                        }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Get All error: " + error.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });

            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put one more boolean column called "fetched data" instead of datatime of creation or update. When it is inserted very first time, you can put the "fetched data" value to false and when it is fetched by the client, you can change it to "true" means it is already fetched. You can fetch the data based on this column value like "fetched data=false" in your query.

You can implement GCM, whenever fresh data will be available to the server it will send it to the client automatically. Hope it will help you.

Comment: can please give some example because i still dont understand. remember i am new in development

Answer (score 0):

`    Main_Table

```
Id(primary key)  Name       Age
1                Balvier    28
2                Kagis      23


User_Table_9920018278

Id(Primary key of Main_Table as Foreign Key)
1

User_Table_9768466084   

Id(Primary key of Main_Table as Foreign Key)    
1   
2   `
```

GCM is more efficient way to do it, as i said whenever new data will be available to the server, server informs to client automatically. And I tell you steps to fetch data efficiently:

1. Get the unique id from the client like his phone number and create a table namely that unique number so that every user has separate unique table which has only one column which contains
     a. the primary key of main data table as a foreign key
2. Whenever you insert new data to the main_table, create another entry in the user table also by passing the newly created row's primary key as foreign key.
3. GCM informs user to download the newly created data to download, or if the data is smaller upto 4kb, you can send the data with gcm notification itself. No need to implement step 2,4,5,6.
4. On recieve of the notification you check only the user table, is there any row in the user_table.
5. if yes, then get foreign key of that newly inserted data from user_table and get the whole newly inserted data from the Main_table based on the primary key you get from user table as foreign key.
6. delete the row from the user_table as you already fetched it.